# Determine data model by C preprocessor

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc, integer, c-preprocessor

I want to write a .h file conforming to C89 that would be understood by most C preprocessors like gcc, cl (Visual Studio) etc. and that would determine the data model used, i.e. how many bits the `(unsigned) short`, `(unsigned) int` and `(unsigned) long` types occupy. Where can I find the necessary macros? For instance, are there macros I can evaluate in order to find out whether the data model is e.g. ILP32, LP64, LLP64 or something else? It is fine for me to use compiler-specific macros, but I do not want to use architecture-specific or OS-specific macros. If possible, please also provide the necessary macros to check which compiler is used. Thank you!

**ADDED 2:** The goal is to allow for type definitions depending on the data model. For instance, if `long` is at least 48-bit wide, a 48-bit key type could be defined as `long`, but if not, I would need a `struct` for that. On the other hand, I do not want to rely on anything not guaranteed by C89, like "`long` is either 32-bit or 64-bit, so if `ULONG_MAX != 0xFFFFFFFFlu`, then long is wider than 48-bit", which does not have to be true on all C89-conforming compilers.

**ADDED 1:** [Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros), the predefined GCC macros are described. Hence I can do the following:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#define SHRT_BIT __SHRT_WIDTH__
#define INT_BIT __INT_WIDTH__
#define LONG_BIT __LONG_WIDTH__
#elif ???
# ???
#endif

printf(
    "short is %u-bit\n"
    "int is %u-bit\n"
    "long is %u-bit\n",
    SHRT_BIT, INT_BIT, LONG_BIT
);
```

Are there similar macros for other widely used compilers like cl (Visual Studio), which I could add at the location of the `???` in the code?

Comment: To find compiler-specific macros, please consult their documentation. -- Have you looked into the standards? Since long the standard header "limits.h" provides implementation-defined limits.

Comment: From `limits.h`, I can access `ULONG_MAX`, yes, but for instance, some day in the future, unsigned long could be 128 bits wide, which means that I cannot just say that if `ULONG_MAX != 0xFFFFFFFFlu`, then it is 64 bits wide. On the other hand, if it is 32 bits, then 2^64-1 cannot be expressed as an integer constant and I cannot check if it is 64 bits wide.

Comment: You might want to [edit] your question to show your use case. Perhaps this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thanks, I tried to clarify my goal in the question.

Comment: Do you actually need preprocessor, or could you manage with compile time constant? If latter, then you could simply have `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(type)`.

Comment: Yes, I need the preprocessor because my type definitions should depend on that. For instance, types that occupy between 33 and 64 bits, like 48-bit keys, could fit into the integral type `(unsigned) long` on 64-bit systems, but not on 32-bit systems; there, I would need a `struct`.

Comment: GCC's documentation says to these macros: "_You should not use these macros directly; instead, include the appropriate headers._" -- Your comment "_I need the preprocessor because my type definitions should depend on that._" should be rather in your question, as it seems to be the core reason.

Comment: Thanks, I added this into the question. -- Why should one not use these gcc macros directly? Which macros can be used instead? And if they were purely for internal usage, why are they documented in the manual?

Comment: I deleted my comment on using fixed width C99 types from `stdint.h` because I noticed you wanted C89 only. However, I think most compilers which don't support C99 still have `stdint.h` and those really bad ones that don't can be covered by custom `stdint.h` file. So, I think you should just require that header. It's not productive to try accomodate compilers that have been broken for over 20 years.

Comment: Thank you, I will think about moving everything from C89 to C99. Maybe that would be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You can `#include <limits.h>` and test the values of `SHRT_MAX`, `USHRT_MAX`, `INT_MAX`, `UINT_MAX`, `LONG_MAX`, and `ULONG_MAX`.

For the signed types, if the maximum value is at least 1,073,741,824 (2<sup>30</sup>), the type has at least 32 bits (31 for the value and 1 for the sign), and similarly for other powers of two. For the unsigned types, one fewer bit is indicated (no sign bit), so comparing to 2,147,483,648 (2<sup>31</sup>) would indicate whether the type has at least 32 bits.

These of course give you only the *width* of a type, the number of bits used for the value and sign (if present). Its actual size may be larger due to padding bits.

Comment: We have `ULONG_MAX >= 2^32 - 1` by C89 standard. But if `ULONG_MAX > 2^32 - 1`, how can I find out, in preprocessing directives, how many bits `unsigned long` has?

Comment: @Kolodez: Test each width you care about.

Comment: If I write `#if (ULONG_MAX == 0xFFFFFFFFlu) CRLF ... CRLF #elif (ULONG_MAX == 0x1FFFFFFFFlu) CRLF ...`, I would get a warning if the first comparison is true because, in those cases, the second integer constant is not representable anymore.

Comment: @Kolodez: If the first comparison is true, the compiler (while preprocessing) should not evaluate the expression in the `#elif`. If it is, try rewriting the code as `#else` with an `#if` inside it. If the compiler still evaluates the expression then, it is buggy.